# how to use "getresponsestatus" in google api calendar

Tags: api, calendar, google-calendar-api, response

I'm working in a project and I need to consult the attendees response. I want to create a script that every hours check if some attendee change your response status, but I can't find any documentation how this works, an example of my code when I insert the event:

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
       $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
      $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
      $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary' => $summary,
        'location' => $location,
        'description' => $descripcion,
        'colorId'=> "5",
        'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => $datetimeini,
        'timeZone' => 'America/Caracas'
        ),
        'end' => array(
         'dateTime' => $datetimeini,
         'timeZone' => 'America/Caracas'
        ),
        'recurrence' => array(
         'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=1'
        ),
        'attendees' => array(
         array('email' => $paciente,'responseStatus'=> 'needsAction'),
         array('email' => $doctor)
        ),
        'reminders' => array(
         'useDefault' => FALSE,
         'overrides' => array(
           array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 12 * 60),
           array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 60)
         ),
        ),
        ));


     $new_event = null;
     $new_event_id = "";

     $new_event = $service->events->insert($idcalendar, $event);

     if($new_event!=null){
       $new_event_id= $new_event->getid();
       $event = $service->events->get($idcalendar,$new_event_id);
       $response = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee($client);
       if($event != null){
         $resultado=array(
           "respuesta"=>"exitoso",
           "id evento"=>$event->getid(),
           "sumario"=>$event->getSummary(),
           "estado"=>$event->getstatus(),
           "response"=>$event->getresponseStatus()
         );
       }else{
           echo 'hay problemas.';
         }
```

If I try this code on response I just get `null`. I want to get the real response.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Events: watch`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch) method which watches for changes to Events resources.

> HTTP request
>
> ```
> POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/watch
> ```

In the request body, supply data with the following structure:

> ```
> {
>   "id": string,
>   "token": string,
>   "type": string,
>   "address": string,
>   "params": {
>     "ttl": string
>   }
> }
> ```